# need to simplify a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

need to simplify this.
$$\tan20^{\circ}\cos50^{\circ}+\cos40^{\circ}.$$

I have tried to express $\cos40^{\circ}$ in terms of $\sin20^{\circ}$ and $\cos 20^{\circ}$ but that does not help.

Comment: how did you express cos 40 in terms of sin 20 and cos 20

Comment: @EpicGuy sounds like $cos(2\theta)$

Comment: cos40=(cos20)^2-(sin20)^2

Comment: yes @Sabyasachi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier: start with $\cos50^\circ=\sin40^\circ$ as suggested by Sabayasachi, then
$$\tan20^\circ\cos50^\circ+\cos40^\circ=\frac{\sin20^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}2\sin20^\circ\cos20^\circ+1-2\sin^220^\circ$$
etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:Write $\cos(50^{\circ})$ as $\sin(40^{\circ})$ and $\tan(20^{\circ})$ as $\tan\left(\frac{40^{\circ}}2\right)$ using the [formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x%2F2%29):

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan x\cos(90^\circ-2x)+\cos2x=\tan x\sin2x+\cos2x$$

Using  [Double angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) formula,

this becomes $$t\cdot\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ where $t=\tan x$